# Append a select picker with AJAX

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, struts2

I'm trying to populate a Bootstrap select with AJAX.
When I do it for a simple select it works but when I try it for bootstrap `selectpicker`, it does not work. I have searched and I found that I should refresh my `selectpicker` but I don't know how I can go about doing that.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "readDistricts?four=" + four + "&sfam=" + sfam,
    data: JSON.stringify(four),
    data: JSON.stringify(sfam),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    success: function(res) {
        // alert(res.articles.length);
        console.log(res.articles.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < res.articles.length; i++) {
            // alert(res.articles[i].CNUF_FOURNISSEUR);
            // alert(res.articles[i].LIBELLE_ARTICLE);
            console.log(" " + res.articles[i].CNUF_FOURNISSEUR);
            console.log(" " + res.articles[i].LIBELLE_ARTICLE);

            $('#articles').append(
                '<option value=' + res.articles[i].CNUF_FOURNISSEUR + '>' + res.articles[i].LIBELLE_ARTICLE + '</option>'
            );
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my select, it's a struts tag:

```
 <s:select  class="form-control selectpicker"    
    list="sfams" headerKey="0" headerValue="Veuillez selectionner" 
    listValue="LIBELLE_SFAM" listKey="ID_SFAM"  id="sfam"  />
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After AJAX is done, you need to reload the plugin:

`$('#articles').selectpicker('refresh');`

or

```
success: function(data)
{
  $("#articles").html(data).selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

For more info read : https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh